# PHP Is there any way to implement windows cmd /b into php?

Tags: php, cmd, binary, implementation

Is there any way to implement windows cmd /b into php?

I mean, binary file joining. I tried a lot (by file_get_contents & file_put_contents) but it doesn't seems to work...

Comment: [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)/[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) on a resource that was opened with the flags `rb`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$target = 'c:/temp/fileA.dat';
$sources = array(
    'c:/temp/file1.bin',
    'c:/temp/file2.dat',
    'c:/temp/file3.foo',
    'c:/temp/file4.'
);


foreach($sources as $src) {
    $fp = fopen($src, 'rb') or die('fopen failed...');
    file_put_contents($target, $fp, FILE_APPEND); 
}
```

see
http://docs.php.net/fopen
http://docs.php.net/file_put_contents